# How can I collaps the icons of running applications?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, system-tray, plasma, plasma-5

My system tray looks like this:

[image]

before I think it would just organize all windows from the applications in a collapsed way, i.e., that Firefox has one icon, if you click on it you get to see how many it has, and so for the other applications.

Because all windows of all applications gets it own icon in the tray it is almost impossible to see what applications are running and I often end up starting programs over again.

Where can I find this setting?

Answer (score 2):

Right click the task manager (where all those icons are), and pick "Task Manager Settings".

[image]

Under "Grouping and Sorting" you'll be able to pick a behaviour that fits your flow.